# Drawing Trasparent Text on Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, graphics, paint

Im trying to draw a string on top of an Image,The code works but the transparency is not obtained i have used several values for alpha,but does not work.

```
paint.setAlpha(alpha);
```

Can some one tell me what are the range of values for transparency or what im doing wrong here

```
public static Bitmap drawtext(Bitmap src, String txt,int alpha) {
        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setTextSize(18);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setUnderlineText(true);
        canvas.drawText(txt, 20, 25, paint);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: what's alpha? try this `paint.setAlpha(0x80)`.

Comment: @Raghunandan I tried values like 100 what's this 0X80 stand for

Comment: that's the alpha value. Colors are represented as packed ints, made up of 4 bytes: alpha, red, green, blue.

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks Tried it does not work,still opaque text

Comment: use `0x10` an then try. adjust the value accordingly. its not fully transperant. its semi transperant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColor(int)

The setColor will overwrite the alpha value you just set before that call. That should work:

```
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setAlpha(alpha);
```